# javascript autolink urls but avoid recursion

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable, autolink

I'm trying to create an autolink feature in javascript that automatically turns urls into links while the user types (ContentEditable div).

I use this regex:

```
var text = 'Some text containing URLs';
var exp = /(\b(http):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
var newtext = text.replace(exp,"<a href='$1'>$1</a>");
```

The code above works fine, but because the code gets called each time a user types, recursion occurs:

```
<a href='<a href='<a href=' etc.
```

How can I avoid this from happening while still having the script update the text as a user types?

So the question is (thanks @putvande): how do I check if a URL doesn't already contain:

```
<a href='...
```

(I'm not really handy with regex)

Comment: You need to check with your Regex if there are already `<a href..></a>` tags in your code.

Comment: I found a non-regex solution to my problem, before the regex function I strip all tags. See my fiddle jsfiddle.net/gerbenzomp/UJMeR/3 Might not be the most elegant solution, so I'm still very interested in a regex-only solution.

Comment: Hay @Gerben did you fix this ? i need a solution im working on this

Answer (score 0):

You can match only those URL patterns that aren't prefixed with a `>` or a `'`. While this may not be 100% foolproof, it should be good enough to get you started.

```
function urlify(text) {
    var exp = /^\>(\b(http):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
    return text.replace(exp,"<a href='$1'>$1</a>");
}
```

On calling it:

```
urlify('Some text http://example.com containing URLs');
```

returns `"Some text <a href='http://example.com'>http://example.com</a> containing URLs"`

```
urlify("Some text <a href='http://example.com'>http://example.com</a> containing URLs");
```

returns `"Some text <a href='http://example.com'>http://example.com</a> containing URLs"`

Comment: I tried your solution, but for some reason it doesn't do anything

Comment: @Gerben the function parameter uses "test" but the function uses "text" as the variable. I've submitted an edit to correct this.